# Disable user of 0 as first number in input box jquery

Tags: jquery, input

I have an input box:

```
<input class="longboxsmall" type="text" name="number" value=""/>
```

And I want to disallow the number 0 being the first number entered in the box how can I do this??? Can I use Jquery??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$(".longboxsmall").keyup(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    value = value.replace(/^(0*)/,"");
    $(this).val(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="longboxsmall" type="text" name="number" value=""/>
```

**JS**

```
$(".longboxsmall").keyup(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    value = value.replace(/^(0*)/,"");
    $(this).val(value);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input class="longboxsmall" type="text" name="number" value=""/>
```

Try in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5B4B/).

---

IT's good to intercept another events, like blur, change, focusout, etc.
See [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/http://api.jquery.com/category/events/).
Tks @Simen Echholt.

---

Explanation:

`$(".longboxsmall").keyup`

*Jquery take every element with class `longboxsmall` and are ready to call a function on onkeyup event.*

```
var value = $(this).val();
value = value.replace(/^(0*)/,"");
$(this).val(value);
```

*This function uses a regex to replace every `0` in begin (`^`) of value.*

Comment: This can be ignored by pasting text with the mouse. Should also bind to `mousedown/up` and/or `change`

Comment: This only allows the user to type zero, and blocks them typing any further numbers. I want to stop them typing 0 as the first number in the string of numbers

Comment: @user342391 Sorry, but you're wrong. It allows to type anything. Just blocks 0 in first chars. Try here http://jsfiddle.net/s5B4B/.

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Use one of input filter plugins (like [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/taxonomy/term/4275)) with suitable regexp.

Answer (score 0):

In order not to see the 0 in the input and then remove it you can use keypress:

`$('.longboxsmall').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (!$(this).val() && e.which == 48)
        return false;
});`

Answer (score 0):

best way is  prevent typing 0 in the first position while user is typing. we can achieve this by to use keyup event. by that we will avoid many case's like.

1. end user first type say 123 and they add 0 in that like 0123.
2. its prevent copy paste like 0123.

   ```
     $(document).on('keyup','#TextBoxID', function(event){
                   if($(this).val().match(/^0/)){
                     $(this).val('');
                     return false;
                 }
               });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".longboxsmall").keyup(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    value = value.replace(/[^(1*)]+|[^(0*)]+/,"");
    $(this).val(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="longboxsmall" type="text" name="number" value=""/>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code. Code only answers are discouraged on SO.